# How can I run the SQLite VACUUM command within a Java application?

Tags: java, sqlite

**Question:**
I want to allow my Java application to manually run the SQLite VACUUM command? I include a code snippet below. I have tried as a PreparedStatement and as a straight Statement. I have also done an extensive web search for a solution and have found no relevant examples.

**What Happens?**
When I run my code, the system pauses. Looking at the directory, the file size does not decrease when executing my code. RecordSet returns false as well.

But, if I run SQLiteManager via Firefox and run Compact Database, the database does compact. NOTE: I make a copy of the DB before compacting so I can see the difference in size.

**Sanity Checks**
--I make sure the DB is closed by all other applications (including SQLiteManager).
--No known transactions running.
--No exceptions thrown.

**Code Snippet:**
I kept my test code inside. This is NOT production code so error handling etc is available but minimal.

```
try {
    Connection conn = db.getConnection() ;
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder() ;
    sql.append("VACUUM");

    //PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString()) ;
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement() ;
    boolean rs = stat.execute(sql.toString()) ;

    System.out.println("Executed vacuum " + rs ) ;     

    //Testing code--preparedstatement attempts
    //conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    //boolean rs = prep.execute() ;
    //conn.setAutoCommit(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
       //Edited back in after posting to StackOverflow
        System.out.println(
                ".SQLiteVacuum :: exception " + 
                e.getMessage() + " " + e.getClass().getName() );
        e.printStackTrace() ;
    }
```

**Cross References**
Java 1.6+
SQLite 3+
Xerial JDBC Driver

**Addendum**

```
private final String dbJDBCdriverclassname = "org.sqlite.JDBC" ;
private final String dbJDBCpreconnectionstring = "jdbc:sqlite:" ;
        // Setup the driver reference
        Class.forName(dbJDBCdriverclassname) ; //"org.sqlite.JDBC"

        // Create the connection string
        String connstring = dbJDBCpreconnectionstring + this.getDBConnectionFullFileName() ;

        // create the connection
        dbconnection = 
                DriverManager.getConnection(connstring) ; // "jdbc:sqlite:test.db"
```

Comment: Since VACUUM doesn't return anything, you should probably use `executeUpdate()` instead of `execute()`. And please don't `catch (Exception)`. Given the code you posted, it's impossible to know if an exception is thrown or not.

Comment: Thank you. I also tried executeUpdate(). This returns 0. I also changed the simple code to catch SQLException rather than just exception. No exceptions are thrown. Also, I notice that the file does get updated (time stamp) but no compaction/vacuum occurs. I know that no compaction occurs because a subsequent run in SQLite Manager via FireFox does clean the DB file--quite considerably.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean about catch exception. That was just abbreviated to post. My copies to have exception handling. Sorry. I changed to reflect my actual code. (Note: code edited--original code just had Exception e with no output in the catch statement).

Comment: The problem is that 4 of 5 questions here don't handle exceptions as they should. So, since you don't show how you REALLY handle the exceptions, we don't know if you really handle them as you should, or if, as it's often the case (and as it is the case in your original question), you simply ignore them, hiding the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is quite old but if everyone needs here it goes.

```
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();//something to get a connection
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("VACUUM");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    //Something if you like, or not you're the boss!
} finally {
    DBConnection.closeResources(rs, stmt);//something to close all the resources
}
```

With something like this snippet, I got 63KB of savings in a test DataBase of 185KB.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct driver in your data source? Are you configuring it properly? That's the part of the code (or configuration) that we're not seeing.

Also, print a stack trace or something, as the above user said, so that we know whether an exception is being thrown. And it would be nice to know whether Statement's execute method returns true or false.

Comment: Thank you. I also added the code for the connection above--see Addendum. I have not seen any exceptions. The executeUpdate method returns 0 and execute returns false.